# AWS KMS How to 100% sure that it is not stolen from others?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I am proposing to use AWS KMS to encrypt my database. However by boss challenge me that what if the someone in Amazon staff has access to steal my KMS and decrypt my database.
The information inside the database is very important and cannot take any risk other people can decrypt it.

Is there other solution to solve this issue? to make sure no one can steal the Key?

Should we use some on-prem HSM to store the key instead ?

Comment: Since AWS does not provide a mechanism to encrypt storage volumes with a client-supplied key, you're out of luck: it's either KMS or nothing. But even if they did provide that option, you'd have to upload that key to let the database server decrypt the volume, and that would still give them the option to steal it. If they wanted to.

Comment: If you don't trust your vendors, don't use them (and how do you know that that HSM you bought doesn't have a back door?)

Comment: AWS can capture your traffics, data, capture everything so pls don't use AWS, on-prem is the best, return to the 2000s.

Comment: We want to use AWS in a secure way. So is AWS Cloudhsm would be a better option to secure? what is the adv of using CloudHSM instead of KMS?

Comment: CloudHSM serves different use-cases than KMS: you can't use it to encrypt disk volumes, although you could use it to manually encrypt the data before you write it. But it doesn't provide any better security: anyone at AWS who has sufficient rights can see your data.

Comment: You would be much better off hiring a competent cloud security consultant, rather than guessing or asking for opinions from strangers on the Internet.

Comment: AWS KMS is designed so that no one, including AWS employees, can retrieve your plaintext KMS keys from the service ([source](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/faqs/#:~:text=AWS%20KMS%20is%20designed%20so,and%20integrity%20of%20your%20keys.)). Read the various AWS compliance documents around KMS, CMK, and HSM. Review the re:Invent content ([example](https://d1.awsstatic.com/events/reinvent/2019/REPEAT_1_Using_AWS_KMS_for_data_protection,_access_control,_and_audit_SEC340-R1.pdf)).

Comment: @Parsifal your statement that you can't encrypt RDS storage volumes with a client-supplied key is false. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securing-data-in-amazon-rds-using-aws-kms-encryption/ KMS (and HSM) support client-supplied keys.

Comment: @MarkB - when I used the term "client-supplied key" I meant a key that was independent of KMS. That was why the end of that sentence is "it's either KMS or nothing." Perhaps read the entire comment next time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/faqs/) points out, AWS KMS is designed such that

> no one, including AWS employees, can retrieve your plaintext KMS keys from the service.

If you read further down, it also provides links to various articles detailing the specification and design of the KMS. And as you can see from the volumes of these articles, the full scope of design consideration and how it complies with FIPS certification is beyond the scope of this answer.

However, as an example, refer to the [cryptographic details tech paper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/cryptographic-details/intro.html) for some ideas of how it works. There are 2 areas mentioned where keys are present:

1. In the KMS Keys Repository
2. In the HSM modules

**KMS Keys Repository**

The repository serves as durable storage for the keys. Keys are, of course, stored encrypted. The article further explains that the key repository leverages on IAM roles.

> Only under AWS IAM roles and accounts administered by each customer can customer KMS keys be created, deleted, or used to encrypt, decrypt, sign, or verify data.

This is the same way authentication and authorization to any other AWS services are managed. Hence, this is one way to prevent AWS employees from gaining access to the keys. How IAM works and how it is secured is once again beyond the scope of this answer.

**HSM Modules**

Unlike the KMS keys repository, the HSM Modules will have access to the plain text keys. However, the plain text keys are only loaded in-memory for the duration that they are used. They are not durably stored in the HSM modules.

> These keys are made available only on the HSMs and only in memory for the necessary time needed to process your cryptographic request.

Hence, employees with access to these modules would be able to theoretically gain access to these keys. To mitigate this risk, if you go to the [design goals section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/cryptographic-details/design-goals.html), the article further explains the modules use quorum-based access controls.

> Multiple Amazon employees with role-specific access to quorum-based access controls are required to perform administrative actions on the HSMs.

That is, no single employee will have administrative access to these modules. Multiple employees are always required. Once again, how AWS assigns which roles to which employees at which management level is beyond the scope of this answer.

As the question requested, these are just some of the considerations of how the service is secured against AWS employees. For an organization to make a decision on whether to use AWS, usually it should be based on a comprehensive set of security policies and an audit whether AWS complies to these requirements.

**EDIT**

Since you mentioned also how to convince stakeholders, this is usually a business question rather than a technical one.

I would refer them to [AWS compliance](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/programs/) for evidence that AWS goes through rigorous 3rd party audits. Would then point out the security of a system is only as strong as the weakest link. That is, using AWS does not mean we automatically have AWS security. We have to ensure our software, our people, and our processes are secure against exploits. So unless we are sure we have better security profile than AWS (with all their compliance and audits), our focus and worry should be more on securing our resources.

Comment: This is a good answer. I would add to it that KMS and HSM are [FIPS 140-2 certified](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-key-management-service-now-offers-fips-140-2-validated-cryptographic-modules-enabling-easier-adoption-of-the-service-for-regulated-workloads/), which means a third-party independent audit has confirmed that AWS employees do not have access to those keys.

Comment: Thanks the answer, do u have the link that support FIPS 140-2 certified compliances your statement? (independent auit has confirm that employee do not have access?)

Comment: @TheOneTeam To my understanding, and as per the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/faqs/), FIPS 140-2 is for certifying the HSM component only. As I explained, the HSMs are secured using quorum-based access. However, the architecture for KMS involves other components in addition to the HSMs. So, unfortunately, my opinion is that there is no one short answer to your question.

Comment: @TheOneTeam I noticed you also mentioned how to convince stakeholders. Edited answer for this.